# valid json, but JSON.parse gives Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: json

Trying to JSON.parse this json string (http://kclab.ru/test.json ) and getting error. Then check it on http://jsonlint.com - everything is ok. 
What the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
stringifiedJson = $.getJSON("http://kclab.ru/test.json").responseText;
JSON.parse(stringifiedJson)
```

You're running into an escaping issue on your stringified JSON. If you could post the error you're getting it might help.